# Changing Sinatra settings on a per-machine basis

Tags: ruby, sinatra

My development machine is different from my deployment/production servers in some ways that cannot be changed. (For example, my development machine has multiple versions of database servers running on different ports, while each production server has only a single version of the RDBMS running, each instance running on the default port.)

What techniques are available for configuring a Sinatra web application differently on one machine versus another? Ideally, answers would summarize **multiple approaches**, and highlight the one approach that has worked best for the respondent. Any file-based solutions should also (ideally) discuss how to handle this situation in the presence of a unified source control repository between both machines.

*Note that this question/problem is orthogonal to configuring for development mode versus production mode.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to load two configuration files: first, the main one (let's say, `settings.rb`), then a machine-specific one that would override necessary settings (`settings-custom.rb`).

Of course, since you have multiple machines, you have multiple configuration sets. In order to manage them easily, they could be named `settings-$hostname.rb`. Then you could simply symlink the appropriate file to `settings-custom.rb`. For example, on unix:

```
ln -s settings-`hostname`.rb settings-custom.rb
```

If you use source control, you can track all the configuration sets, and ignore `settings-custom.rb` (because it's only a symlink, and doesn't need to be tracked) -- with this method, you won't need to change any code between the machines.